# Adding Alt Tag Column to Media Library List

Tags: media-library

I'd like to add a column in the Media Library that shows that alt tag that way I can quickly add alt tags for all images that don't have one. How could I go about this?

Comment: There's an updated version of this code on woocommerce's github page here [https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Importer-&-Exporter#adding-custom-import-columns-developers](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Importer-&-Exporter#adding-custom-import-columns-developers) Check that out if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code -

```
function wpse_media_extra_column( $cols ) {
    $cols["alt"] = "ALT";
    return $cols;
}
function wpse_media_extra_column_value( $column_name, $id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'alt' )
        echo get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
}
add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'wpse_media_extra_column' );
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'wpse_media_extra_column_value', 10, 2 );
```

It could go to `functions.php` file or into your plugin.