# Editing alt text in media library

Tags: media-library, accessibility

I added a column to the media library to display the alt text using [this information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137082/adding-alt-tag-column-to-media-library-list), however I'd also like to edit the alt-text entry of each image without having to go into and edit each individual image.  Is there a way to add this ability to edit in the column?

Comment: Keep in mind that the alt text in the Media Library will only be added when you add the images afterward. In other words, any existing alt text (or lack of alt text) within existing Posts/Pages/CPTs will not get overridden, it will remain whatever it was when it was first added to the page. So you may need more than Media Library adjustments depending on your goal.